# Make a div id disappear after a specific date and time

Tags: javascript, css, display

is there a way to make div disappear after a specific date and time?  Like if i build a upcoming event page, how do I make the 1st event, div id=Event1, disappear after the event closes on say March 22, 2020 and 10:00pm?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is very possible, what have you tried doing so far - which part do you need help with?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I am kinda being pro active at the moment n looking for pointers. I’ll build a few event boxes today n then share the code.

Comment: The boxes will be one the home and event schedule page. here is a preview of the event schedule page. still working on formatting. http://zutterdesign.com/pgamtest/event-schedule.htm

Comment: http://zutterdesign.com/pgamtest/event-schedule.htm here is a link to the events pages. any help would  be great. idk where to begin

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here and play around with various Date methods available.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

const d = new Date;

setInterval(() => {
  if (d.getMinutes() > 15) div.innerText = "Event Over :("
}, 100);
```

```html
<div>Ongoing Event</div>
```

Comment: Where do I edit the date? Not that good at edging this type of code. I’ll share a link once it get something built. Basicly on gonna build a container and in the container I’m gonna put a logo, event dates, even names and a button to link to the detailed event page

Comment: @JZDesign Yeah! For now you can accept the answer if it was useful

Comment: http://zutterdesign.com/pgamtest/event-schedule.htm is wher i am at so far